# Question about word order

Tags: word-order

Which is correct to say:

> Mit großem Interesse habe ich in Ihrer Zeitung vom 10. Juni die Meldung über Umweltschutz gelesen, und deshalb möchte ich Ihnen schreiben.

or

> Mit großem Interesse habe ich die Meldung über Umweltschutz in Ihrer Zeitung vom 10. Juni gelesen, und deshalb möchte ich Ihnen schreiben.

Answer (score 6):

Both are correct. But they’re not alone. Also correct are the following and more:

> Ich habe in Ihrer Zeitung vom 10. Juni mit großem Interesse die Meldung über Umweltschutz gelesen, […]
>   In Ihrer Zeitung vom 10. Juni habe ich die Meldung über Umweltschutz mit großem Interesse gelesen, […]
>   Die Meldung über Umweltschutz in Ihrer Zeitung vom 10. Juni habe ich mit großem Interesse gelesen, […]

Word order is basically free, as long as the verb comes second. It does sound weird to bring *ich* too far back, so I would leave it right behind the *habe*, but otherwise almost anything goes.

Answer (score 4):

Both forms are correct and common. Jan even gave additional ones which you can use also.

It is a matter of style, emphasis and readableness. Some forms are quite easy to read and understand, other sound a bit uncommon.

Your first form emphasizes that it is about the newspaper from the 10th of June. 
This could imply there might have been other articles about the theme, but it is about this one.

The second one points out that the news were about environmental protection. This could imply that it is the first news about it, you have read or which was in their newspaper, and that the date merely is for reference.